# How does middleware work in chi routing in Go and what does http.Handler argument refers to in middleware?

Tags: rest, go, http, middleware

```golang
-- routes.go --
package main

import (
    "hotelsystem/pkg/config"
    "hotelsystem/pkg/handlers"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
)

func routes(app *config.AppConfig) http.Handler {
    mux := chi.NewRouter()
    mux.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    mux.Use(WriteToConsole)
    mux.Get("/", handlers.Repo.Home)
    mux.Get("/about", handlers.Repo.About)
    return mux

}
-- middleware.go --
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func WriteToConsole(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Hit the page")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
-- main.go --
package main

import (
    "hotelsystem/pkg/config"
    "hotelsystem/pkg/handlers"
    "hotelsystem/pkg/render"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const portNumber = ":3000"

func main() {
    var app config.AppConfig
    tc, err := render.CreateTemplateCache()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Can't create templatecache", err)
    }
    app.TemplateCache = tc
    app.UseCache = false
    repo := handlers.NewRepo(&app)
    handlers.NewHandlers(repo)
    render.NewTemplate(&app)
    // http.HandleFunc("/", handlers.Repo.Home)
    // http.HandleFunc("/about", handlers.Repo.About)
    // http.ListenAndServe(portNumber, nil)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    portNumber,
        Handler: routes(&app),
    }
    err = srv.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the middleware.

I am using [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) for routing.

What I didn't understand is what does that (next `http.Handler`) argument in the `WriteToConsole` refers to?

Does it refer to our mux router?

Also when I comment down the line `next.ServeHTTP` of function writetoconsole the html is not rendered or anything? can someone explain me what does that next `http.Handler` refers to and what `next.serveHTTP` does?

Comment: the playground can always help you format your code https://play.golang.org/ even more, it can handle multiple files. Hopefully some people in the go community were bold enough to require a unque source of formatting, tanks to them we can now make it happen in our daily life. Please apply, `go fmt` is there to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`next` is the next handler in the "handler chain".

When you do:

```golang
mux.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
mux.Use(WriteToConsole)
mux.Get("/", handlers.Repo.Home)
mux.Get("/about", handlers.Repo.About)
```

You are essentially registering two "handler chains":

```golang
mux.Get("/", middleware.Recoverer(WriteToConsole(handlers.Repo.Home)))
mux.Get("/about", middleware.Recoverer(WriteToConsole(handlers.Repo.About)))
```

Each handler returned by the middleware function has to invoke the `next` handler given to it, i.e. do `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)`, if it doesn't invoke `next` then the chain is broken and the rest of the handlers in that chain will be ignored.

---

A simplified code example may illustrate the chaining better:

```golang
type handler func()

// your handler
func f() { fmt.Println("f") }

// one middleware
func g(next handler) handler {
    return func() {
        fmt.Print("g.")
        next()
    }
}

// another middleware
func h(next handler) handler {
    return func() {
        fmt.Print("h.")
        next()
    }
}
```

With the above you can then do:

```golang
func main() {
    h1 := h(g(f))
    h1()

    h2 := g(h(f))
    h2()

    // And you can chain as many of these as you like
    // and in any order you like.
    h3 := h(g(h(h(h(g(g(h(f))))))))
    h3()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4NXquYsaljr